# What is this UI element called? for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

The one that asks you to select a wireless network?

It looks like a UIAlertView and UIPickerView combined? How do you use it

Comment: it looks more like a UITableView and a UIAlertView.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create your Custom UIAlertView. Check [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html) tutorial out. It might help you.

Now, if you are looking for a **magic class** to resolve the issue without coding, the answer would be: there is no straightforward UI element that will achieve what you are trying to.

Comment: As Pablo mentions, that will be the correct solution since there is no native ui control to do that. Unless you want to establish peer to peer connections with other devices, then you could use GKPeerPickerController, this controller creates all the ui elements required in the workflow to achieve this.